# NHibernate throws "Invalid operation. The connection was closed." exception

Tags: asp.net, database, nhibernate, session, logging

I have a code piece to record user data in Session_End event of Global.asax. It is working but sometimes it throws "Invalid operation. The connection was closed" exception. I have failed to replicate this situation on development server. It only occurs on application server. What is wrong? Thanks.

```
    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            userlog = UserLog.LoadBySessionAndLogoutTime(NHibernateHTTPModule.CurrentSession, Session.SessionID, null);
            userlog.LogoutTime = DateTime.Now;
            UserLog.Update(NHibernateHTTPModule.CurrentSession, userlog);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Mail.SendMail("Error", error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you explain where you open and close your nhibernate session. Unless you say the opposite I'll assume that you use "Open Session in View" pattern.

The user session ends outside of the scope of a request so if you open a nhibernate session on each request it won't be available when you try to log.

You should verify if you have an opened nhibernate session before logging. If none is active, you'll need to open a new one.

Comment: I am opening and closing nhibernate session in each http request. I have a NHibernateHTTPModule which inherits IHttpModule and I am doing opening in OnBeginRequest and closing OnEndRequest events. I did try your suggestion before, I did placed a control to check whether nhibernate connection state is closed and I re-open if it is closed but no luck.

Comment: Do you open a new nhibernate session there and it throws the same error?

Comment: Yes, exacly. I re - open a new session but it keeps giving me the same error. I also tried to re - initiate connection by opening a new one but no. It keeps giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are an Exception relating to an NHibernate operation was thrown somewhere in your code. *Any* NHibernate exception will invalidate the session.

So there is some condition on the application server that is different from your dev environment that contributes to the error. You could try logging it on the application server:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    Exception myError = null;
    if(HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError() != null)
    {
        // log error
        myError = Server.GetLastError();
        ....
    }
}
```

in global.asax will intercept all errors so you can log them.

Comment: this is the logical answer to your problem, there is some error occurring with one of your Nhibernate transaction and the session is closed after that.. Make sure you check if the session exists before logging.

Comment: I'll try the Application_Error event. Baz1nga, I tried to check if session exists before logging and reinitialized if none exists but I had no luck.